# Executing command lines from Excel using VBScript or connecting to domain Active Directory

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript, active-directory

I need to create a function in Excel that allows me to read a value form one cell that contains the name of an Active Directory Group and obtain the members of that group and load that information in another cell.

Comment: Okay, that's a nice goal. How are you trying to achieve it?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

I use something like this to run my Ruby scripts from Excel.
Create a button and edit the macro behind it.
Replace the command and script executed with the one you need for your AD search.
The example takes the value of cell A2 and uses it as input in the script to produce the output in cell D2.

```
Sub Knop1_Klikken()
    Dim objShell As Object
    Dim objWshScriptExec As Object
    Dim objStdOut As Object
    Dim rline As String
    Dim strline As String
    Dim arg As String
    Dim command As String

    arg = Worksheets("Blad1").Range("A2")
    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    command = "cmd.exe /S /C ruby ""C:\Users\Gebruiker\ruby\excel\run.rb"" " & arg
    Set objWshScriptExec = objShell.Exec(command)
    Set objStdOut = objWshScriptExec.StdOut

    While Not objStdOut.AtEndOfStream
        rline = objStdOut.ReadLine
        If rline <> "" Then strline = strline & vbCrLf & rline
    Wend
    Worksheets("Blad1").Range("D2") = strline
End Sub
```

Comment: The command i am using is "dsquery group -name UIO_GRP_POC_GCE| dsget group -members > C:\Users\moscosoe\memberlist3.txt", i change that on the code you gave me and worked perfectly, thanks.